# How do I make my JDA bot work on a server instead of just DMs?

Tags: java, discord, discord-jda

I'm trying to set up a discord bot using java (JDA) but I'm having some trouble when trying to use it on a server. It works fine with direct messages but for some reason it doesn't on a server. I set the project up through intellij as a Maven project.

I started out with a

```
public void onMessageReceived(MessageReceivedEvent event) {
        event.getChannel().sendMessage("test").queue();
}
```

Which worked fine in the DM's, but not in a server.

Here is what I tried so far:

1.

I changed it from message received to:

```
public void onGuildMessageReceived(GuildMessageReceivedEvent event) {
        event.getChannel().sendMessage("test").queue();
}
```

This still doesn't wok on my server, and it doesn't work in dms either.

2.
I changed the permissions from the bot (I had the ones I needed first but now it has admin so all permissions)

Still, the bot only works without guilded message in DMs. I hope you guys can help, and just in case you need it, here is my entire code as it is right now (I replaced my token with "TOKEN" for privacy purposes):

Main.java:

```
import net.dv8tion.jda.api.JDA;
import net.dv8tion.jda.api.JDABuilder;
import net.dv8tion.jda.api.OnlineStatus;

public class Main {

    public static JDA jda;
    public static String[] prefixes = {"!", "-", "~", "/"};

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception{

        //jda settings
        jda = new JDABuilder("TOKEN").build();
        jda.getPresence().setStatus(OnlineStatus.IDLE);

        jda.addEventListener(new Commands());

    }

}
```

And here is Commands.java:

```
import net.dv8tion.jda.api.OnlineStatus;
import net.dv8tion.jda.api.entities.MessageChannel;
import net.dv8tion.jda.api.entities.TextChannel;
import net.dv8tion.jda.api.events.message.MessageReceivedEvent;
import net.dv8tion.jda.api.events.message.guild.GuildMessageReceivedEvent;
import net.dv8tion.jda.api.hooks.ListenerAdapter;

import java.util.*;

public class Commands extends ListenerAdapter {

    String[] info = {"info", "zuipbot", "zuipen", "jo", "hoi", "hallo", "30en"};
    List<String> infoList = Arrays.asList(info);

    public void onGuildMessageReceived(GuildMessageReceivedEvent event) {
        event.getChannel().sendMessage("adsfdsf").queue();
        Main.jda.getPresence().setStatus(OnlineStatus.ONLINE);
        String[] args = event.getMessage().getContentRaw().split(" ");
        for (int i = 0; i < Main.prefixes.length; i++) {

            //check if the message starts with one of the correct prefixes
            if (args[0].startsWith(Main.prefixes[i])) {

                //remove the prefix
                args[0] = args[0].substring(1);

                //set the idle timer
                TimerTask task = new TimerTask() {
                    public void run() {
                        Main.jda.getPresence().setStatus(OnlineStatus.IDLE);
                    }
                };

                Timer timer = new Timer();

                long delay = 120000L;
                timer.schedule(task, delay);

                //commands
                if (infoList.contains(args[0].toLowerCase())) {
                    event.getChannel().sendTyping().queue();
                    event.getChannel().sendMessage("info").queue();
                }

                if (args[0].toLowerCase() == "stop") {
                    event.getChannel().sendMessage("Are you sure you want to stop?").queue();
                    Main.jda.shutdown();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Edit: this is my pom.xml (So Im using the most recent version of JDA):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>Me.LoudMines</groupId>
    <artifactId>ZuipBot</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.15</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.15</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.dv8tion</groupId>
            <artifactId>JDA</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.0_214</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>jcenter</id>
            <name>jcenter-bintray</name>
            <url>https://jcenter.bintray.com</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

</project>
```

Comment: 1) Update JDA, 2) stop using the deprecated constructor for JDABuilder

Comment: @Minn
Thank you for your response. 
1) I have updated the question to show that I am using the most recent JDA
2) I was unaware this constructor is deprecated. Could you be more specific/tell me the new way to construct a builder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use the deprecated JDABuilder constructor, to get the JDA instance use this instead:
https://ci.dv8tion.net/job/JDA/javadoc/net/dv8tion/jda/api/JDABuilder.html#createDefault(java.lang.String)

---

```
JDA jda = JDABuilder.createDefault(token).build();
```